# Make width auto of text block

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to set height and widhth of dynamically created text block to auto?

```
TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = "Text Block", Width = 140, Height = 40, FontSize = 20 };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting width (or height) to `Double.NaN` is the equivalent of setting the width to `auto` in XAML.

```
TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = "Text Block", Width = Double.NaN, Height = Double.NaN, FontSize = 20 };
```

Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx)